# How to run : Object execute throws ExecutionException

Tags: java, outlook

I'm trying to run the code which will call the already filled outlook new mail window. I use this nice tutorial :
http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseMicrosoftIntegration/article.html
(point 2.2)

There is :

```
public class SendEmail extends AbstractHandler {

@Override   
public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException { 
    (...)
```

and now super-silly question... how to run this code? There is no main method
I tried to made another class :

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        outlook test = new outlook();
    }
}
```

It doesn't work.

Comment: did you look at those links "See Eclipse RCP for details" / "See Eclipse command for details"

Comment: you have to create your own class containing the main method and create the instance of the Sendmail. Then call execute.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't require main.
(If you are using eclipse and if you have done everything correctly) right click on project and Run As=>Eclipse Application.

To see this in action.
You can create sample project.
1. Create New "Plug-in project
2. Select "Hello World"
3. Finish and Run As=>Eclipse Application.

Click on Eclipse Button on toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

An handler is always associated to a command to execute. This is particularly helpful in the Eclipse Plugin development. I recommend creating a plugin with some buttons / menu to click on. If you have define correctly the handler, the method execute overridden from AbstractHandler should be triggered.
An example is here: https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCommands/article.html